# Generating means of a variable using dummy variables & foreach in Stata

Tags: foreach, stata

My dataset includes TWO main variables `X` and `Y`.

- Variable `X` represents distinct codes (e.g. 001X01, 001X02, etc) for multiple computer items with different brands.
- Variable `Y` represents the tax charged for each code of variable `X` (e.g. 15 = 15% for 001X01) at a store.

I've created categories for these computer items using dummy variables (e.g. `HD` dummy variable for Hard-Drives, takes value of 1 when variable `X` represents a HD, etc). I have a list of over 40 variables (two of them representing `X` and `Y`, and the rest is a bunch of dummy variables for the different categories I've created for computer items).

I would like to display the averages of all these categories using a loop in Stata, but I'm not sure how to do this.

For example the code:

```
mean Y if HD == 1


Mean estimation                     Number of obs    =       5

--------------------------------------------------------------
             |       Mean   Std. Err.     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+------------------------------------------------
   Tax       |        7.1   2.537716      1.154172    15.24583
```

gives me the mean Tax for the category representing Hard Drives. How can I use a loop in Stata to automatically display all the mean Taxes charged for each category? I would do it by hand without a problem, but I want to repeat this process for multiple years, so I would like to use a loop for each year in order to come up with this output.

My goal is to create a separate Excel file with each of the computer categories I've created (38 total) and the average tax for each category by year.

Answer (score 2):

Why bother with the loop and creating the indicator variables? If I understand correctly, your initial dataset allows the use of a simple `collapse`:

```
clear all
set more off

input ///
code tax str10 categ
1 0.15 "hd"
2 0.25 "pend"
3 0.23 "mouse"
4 0.29 "pend"
5 0.16 "pend"
6 0.50 "hd"
7 0.54 "monitor"
8 0.22 "monitor"
9 0.21 "mouse"
10 0.76 "mouse"
end

list

collapse (mean) tax, by(categ)

list
```

To take to Excel you can try `export excel` or `put excel`.

Run `help collapse` and `help export` for details.

---

**Edit**

Because you insist, below is an example that gives the same result using loops. 
I assume the same data `input` as before. Some testing using this example database
with `expand 1000000`, shows that speed is virtually the same. But *almost surely*,
you (including your *future you*) and your readers will prefer `collapse`. 
It is much clearer, cleaner and concise. It is even prettier.

```
levelsof categ, local(parts)
gen mtax = .

quietly {
    foreach part of local parts {
        summarize tax if categ == "`part'", meanonly
        replace mtax = r(mean) if categ == "`part'"
    }
}

bysort categ: keep if _n == 1
keep categ mtax
```

Stata has features that make it quite different from other languages. Once you
start getting a hold of it, you will find that many things done with loops elsewhere,
can be made loop-less in Stata. In many cases, the latter style will be preferred.

See corresponding help files using `help <command>` and if you are not familiarized with *saved results* (e.g. `r(mean)`), type `help return`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. My data does not really have the CATEG variable, only CODE & TAX, the code describes an item (e.g. hd) but every code is unique, even though they belong to the same category (so I have like 50 different codes - all of them are for hard drives). I created a dummy variables to "categorize" the items. Also, I will NOT be using all of the CODES, some of the data includes computer parts that I'm not interested about.

Comment: Collapse definitely does what I'm looking for, I just have to make some minor modifications (e.g. creating a category variable based on the dummy variables). Thank you  Roberto Ferrer.I would still love to learn how to use loops in a situation like this, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There is no advantage to creating indicator (you say dummy) variables here when the same information is already available in your categorical variable `X` (so why you think you need to create one is not clear). As @Roberto Ferrer points out, no loop is needed here but available loop technique is prominently documented e.g. http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/try-all-values-with-foreach/index.html

Answer (score 1):

A supplement to Roberto's excellent answer: After `collapse`, you *will* need a loop to export the results to excel.

```
levelsof categ, local(levels)
foreach x of local levels {
export  excel  `x', replace
}
```

I prefer to use numerical codes for variables such as your category variable. I then assign them value labels.  Here's a version of Roberto's code which does this and which, for closer correspondence to your problem, adds a "year" variable

```
input code tax  categ year
1 0.15  1 1999
2 0.25  2 2000
3 0.23  3 2013
4 0.29  1 2010
5 0.16  2 2000
6 0.50  1 2011
7 0.54  4 2000
8 0.22  4 2003
9 0.21  3 2004
10 0.76 3 2005
end

#delim ;
label define catl
1 hd
2 pend
3 mouse
4 monitor
;
#delim cr
label values categ catl
collapse (mean) tax, by(categ year)

levelsof categ, local(levels)
foreach x of local levels {
export  excel  `:label (categ) `x'', replace
}
```

The  `#delim ;` command makes it possible to easily list each code on a separate line. The"label" function in the `export` statement is an extended macro function to insert a value label into the file name.